# Rails: has many relationship - determine which related object from within method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, relationships

I have two classes with the following relationships/methods:

```
class Bar
  has_many :foos

  def bar_method
    #puts the specific foo that called it
  end
end

class Foo
  belongs_to :bar

  def foo_method
    bar.bar_method
  end
end
```

When calling foo_method on an instance of Foo, how I can tell which Foo called this from within bar_method? Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is! Here is a simple way ;)

```
class Bar
  has_many :foos

  def bar_method foo
    puts foo
  end
end

class Foo
  belongs_to :bar

  def foo_method
    bar.bar_method self
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was passing self already but it looked like overkill. Figured I'd check if there was any way to infer it automatically. Thanks again.